# ¿Por qué no debería reescribir commits publicados?

Tags: git, control-de-versiones

Siempre leo y decimos que es *peligroso* reescribir commits publicados en `git` (es decir, que puedan existir en repositorios de terceros).

**¿Qué problemas ocasiona, puntualmente?** ¿Por qué ocurren esos problemas?

Comment: No es peligroso, es contraindicado. Lo que ocurre cuando reescribes la historia es que generas un nuevo HEAD y al hacer push, git te pide que primero hagas un fetch y un merge del HEAD que está en el repositorio remoto. Posteriormente, al hacer push provocas que tus colaboradores tengan que registrar el mismo rebase y por lo tanto incluso más merges adicionales en sus repositorios locales haciendo complicado revisar la historia de los commits

Answer (score 5):

No se recomienda hacer `git commit --amend` ni `git reset` en repositorios públicos por la sencilla razón de que los commits nuevos reemplazan a los viejos y en la historia de tu repositorio se va a ver como si un pedazo de ella simplemente hubiera desaparecido.

Sin embargo, estas herramientas existen por una razón y dicha razón es que son útiles para pulir o mejorar la historia de nuestros repositorios. Por ejemplo, si tuvieras un repositorio con un montón de `commits` inútiles u obsoletos entonces tienes la oportunidades de juntarlos con los `commits` que sí son significantes y al final la historia de tu repositorio se verá ordenada y limpia.

Puedes ver más información sobre ocasiones en que es útil reescribir la historia de los repositorios [acá](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history).

La nota de precaución es para que los demás desarrolladores que pudieron haber clonado tu repositorio no tengan problemas navegando en la historia de commits. Si eso pasa y se hacen varios `amends` simultáneos podría causar una confusión bastante grande en el repositorio aunque la probabilidad es muy reducida.

Puedes ver un poco más a detalle esto [acá](https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) (en inglés).

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema es que los otros usuarios podrían realizar trabajo sobre los commits originales. Ya que las personas que ya tienen la historia original en general seguirán trabajando sobre ella, al intentar mezclar los cambios se encuentran versiones distintas de los commits y la situación es confusa.

Por ejemplo, dado un repo con tres commits (A, B, C), mientras Juan trabaja en un commit D, alguien cambia B y C (por ejemplo cambia el mensaje o arregla un error), cuando Juan intenta hacer un push de su commit D se encuentra con que no puede porque es non-fast-forward (o sea que hay cosas en origin que no están localmente y se perderían).

Gráficamente la situación es la siguiente:

```
A - B - C - D (master)
  \ B'- C'    (origin/master)
```

Entonces, suele suceder que esto genere merges innecesarios, ya que suele ocurrir que mediante un pull y un push se vuelvan los commits B y C originales a la historia.

```
A - B - C - D - M   (master, origin/master)
  \ B'- C'- - /
```

Por eso es importante, que si es necesario cambiar la historia en git, comunicarlo a todos los que trabajan en ella para que puedan prepararse.

Para *preparase*, una forma simple que funciona en muchos casos es utilizando `git pull --rebase` en estos casos, que adapta nuestro commit a la nueva historia:

```
A - B'- C'- D'(master)
```

Los casos más complejos se resuelven utilizando `git rebase` y `git reset`.

> Siempre leo y decimos que es peligroso reescribir commits publicados en git.

Entonces no es peligroso, sino confuso. En algunos casos es incluso bueno hacerlo, pero siempre avisando a los demás para que estén preparados. Es muy común que estos cambios se realicen en ramas específicas en las que trabaja un pequeño grupo de personas y la comunicación es más fácil.

El único caso peligroso, es cuando erradamente se intenta eliminar una contraseña o algún secreto cuando este ya fue publicado ya que es muy posible que una vez publicada haya copias distribuidas.

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los objetivos del control de versiones es tener un historial de versiones de código, cambios realizados, etc. Es "peligroso" ya que si sobre escribes una revisión, simplemente nunca podrás acceder a ella, "un pedazo de la historia se pierde en el tiempo"...

Comment: Esto no es cierto, los commit reescritos siguen existiendo en el repositorio local y el remoto. Pero al generar nuevos HEADS, git obliga a todas las personas que quieren hacer push del repositorio a realizar merges adicionales ocasionando que la historia sea aún menos lineal.

Comment: entonces debo decir, cuando realizas un merge, en lugar de sobre escribir? =P

Comment: Esto explica una razón filosófica en general... y es válido, pero no explique porque es específicamente peligroso en git, y creo que eso es la pregunta.

Comment: entonces elimino mi respuesta ya que no es útil, ustedes que piensan ?

Comment: @Elenasys los commits no se sobreescriben, cuando haces un rebase generas nuevos commits con su propio hash, El problema puntual es que al revisar la historia de commits, solo verías una maraña de commits y de mensajes en lugar de la descripción evolutiva de lo que ha ocurrido en el desarrollo del proyecto. Como dato adicional, cuando un commit tiene más de un parent (por ejemplo un merge normal o un octopus), se puede acceder a los otros parents con la sintaxis HEAD^1 HEAD^2 y en los octopus también HEAD^3 en adelante