# ¿Como edito un mensaje incorrecto en un push de git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, control-de-versiones

Escribí algo que no quería en el comentario del commit.

```
git commit -m "comentario indeseado"

git push
```

¿Como puedo cambiar o actualizar el mensaje?

**Ojo, ya hice push y quiero quitar el mensaje en el repositorio también.**

¿Es posible?

Comment: Creo que no es exactamente el mismo caso/pregunta. Saludos

Comment: La respuesta aceptada de la otra pregunta no soluciona el problema de esta así que no considero que sea duplicada

Answer (score 7, accepted):

==> Sustituye el mensaje del ultimo commit así:

```
git commit --amend -m "nuevo mensaje"

git push --force
```

Hacer esto se considera una mala practica y tiene sus riesgos, como se menciona en este enlace:

[¿Por qué no debería reescribir commits publicados?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/1275/2509)

Comment: @rnrneverdies no es parecida a una pregunta tuya? Senti un déjà vu

Comment: Deberías agregar que tiene sus riesgos hacer esto, asi como esta da la sensación que es un tramite y nada mas. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/por-qu%C3%A9-no-deber%C3%ADa-reescribir-commits-publicados

Comment: como que no? estas pisando un commit con otro commit, si alguien descargo el commit previo, es como si tuvieran 2 repositorios diferentes. El otro se vera obligado a hacer --force otra vez y el problema le vuelve al que hizo --force en primer lugar.

Comment: @rnrneverdies gracias, totalmente cierto

Comment: Es una manera, como bien se ha dicho, una muy mala práctica.
En mi caso lo que he hecho cuando me equivoco en el mensaje, es ir a mi repositorio remoto (en el caso de que sea en github por ejemplo) y realizo un comentario.
O, hablo inmediatamente con el team para que no realicen pull y realizar el push forced con la descripción nueva del commit.